Modifying the text color of List Item on Selection in QML ListView
I am trying to update and reset the text color of current selected list item in QML ListView and resetting the color to default when the current selected list item becomes the previous Item in the ListView.
But all the time the selected items are being visible with default color either current selected item or previous item.
Below is the sample code that i have tried to in order to achieve the same, but unable to understand what is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated
MsgItemDelegate.qml
import QtQuick 2.9

import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ItemDelegate {
    id: root

    signal buttonClicked

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
        root.buttonClicked()
        }
    }

    Label {
        id: txtLbl

        text: model.name
        color: lv.isCurrentItem ? "white" : "blue"
    }
} 

Main.qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    ListView {
        id: lv
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {name: "Hai"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai1"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai2"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai3"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai4"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai5"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai6"}
            ListElement {name: "Hai7"}
        }

        delegate: MsgItemDelegate {
                onButtonClicked: {
                    lv.currentIndex = index
                    console.error("==============ListView.currentIndex==>", ListView.isCurrentItem)
                }
        }

        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
    }
}


I found the solution by making the below change.
Label {
        id: txtLbl
        text: model.name
        color: root.ListView.isCurrentItem ? "white" : "blue"
    }

Thanks everyone for your time.
